# using "neo4j-driver" with nodejs and ES5

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I am using the "neo4j-driver" module for nodejs to connect to my neo4j instance.

The "results" that are passed to me when "session.run()" completes are a JSON object that represents  StatementResult data, and not a StatementResult instance, per se.  Is there a guide somewhere that assists those of us that are using ES5 and not ES6?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Joel

Comment: ES6 (or ES2015) and Typescript are not synonymous (see https://johnpapa.net/es5-es2015-typescript/). Also, can you explain the difference between "data" and "instance"?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I have decided to migrate my module to es6, to be able to use all of the features that the neo4j module provides.  This module will need to be referenced from existing es5 modules.  Any suggestions for making my es6 module available to the es5 modules?  I tried using "export" on my class definition, but "require()" returns an empty object in my es5 code.  What am I missing?

Comment: As a follow-up to my last comment:  In my es6 module, I am using the expression "export let v1 = {func1: function() {}...}" to expose my es6 module functions to my es5 modules, it seems that there would be a best-practice for doing this...can you refer me to such a "best practice"?